# Can't draw line using CC3LineNode in cocos3d

Tags: ios, cocos3d

i am a newbie in cocos3d. I wan to draw a line using cc3linenode.

Here is the code

```
float arr_location[] = {x,y,z, dx,dy, dz };
CC3LineNode* lineNode = [CC3LineNode nodeWithName: @"Line test"];
[lineNode populateAsLineStripWith: 2
                         vertices: arr_location
                        andRetain: YES];
lineNode.color = ccGREEN;

[_lines addObject:lineNode];
[_activeWorld addChild:lineNode];
```

But when i try this, i get an error like this

```
Instance method populateAsLineStripWith: vertices: andRetain: is not found(return type defaults to 'id')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you import?

```
#import "CC3ParametricMeshNodes.h"
```

you error gives you unfound instance of method, so you just need to make right import with that method

found answer [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/instance-method-populateasspherewithradiusandtessellation-not-found/)

proof [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7bqd.jpg)

Comment: k. But cc3line node is a type of mesh node. so what else i ve to import ??

Comment: yes i found this method in CC3ParametricMeshNodes, two screenshots of using this [method](http://imgur.com/zv1Gs2N), and from what [class](http://imgur.com/KNQbb7q) it is

Comment: another issue comes tat is type compatibility. vertices needs cc3vector type arguments. But i ve given **float**. SO i changed type of ** arr_location** to **cc3vector** type. Still i get warning . . .

Comment: look this [example]https://github.com/cocos3d/cocos3d/blob/master/Demos/CC3Performance/CC3Performance/Classes/CC3PerformanceScene.m#L161

Comment: But i ve found small prob. How to assign values for vertices. I tried using cc3vector array. But still confused about the positions of line.